# Searching multiple fields in SOLR

Tags: solr

I am trying to search on 2 fields without having to specify a field name in the query. In my schema.xml I have added 2 fields that correspond to 2 columns in a database table.

```
<field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="description" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

In addition I added a 3rd field which I want to use as a destination in "copyField"
and also as the "defaultSearchField"

```
<field name="combinedSearch" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<copyField source="*" dest="combinedSearch"/>

<uniqueKey>title</uniqueKey> 

<defaultSearchField>combinedSearch</defaultSearchField>
```

Now in the Solr Admin UI, if I enter some title it will return results but if I enter some description it won't return anything.
It seems only the first field is used for searching. Am I using  copyField and defaultSearchField in the right way?
I've restarted the solr server and regenerated the index.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi dev, how you solve this problem now? Can you post the right answer?

Answer (score 2):

Probably it ends in the same result, but for your information, i use copyField at the end of the schema.xml (but i dont think, the order is relevant) in the following syntax:

```
   <copyField source="title" dest="combinedSearch" />
   <copyField source="description" dest="combinedSearch" />
```

next:

```
<field name="combinedSearch" type="string"
```

If `type="text"` is the better choise depends on the definition of "string". If you are using default fieldTypes, `type="string"` could better for your case, because for `string` there is no analyzing per default, which means (probably) there is also no tokenyzing.

//update

An other way instead of copyfields is to use the (e)dsimax query parser. On `solrconfig.xml` you can specify all the field you like to search by default, like this:

```
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
         will be overridden by parameters in the request
      -->
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <float name="tie">0.01</float>
       <bool name="tv">true</bool>
       <str name="qf">
             title^1 description^1
       </str>
     ...
```

Comment: have you tried it? Is it working? I mean can you copy two fields into one? Like you did two sources and one dest?

Comment: @manurajhada >have you tried it? Is it working?< sure, it's working on production since years. ;-) > I mean can you copy two fields into one?< right! An other solution is to use the (e)dismax query parser. There you can define the fields you like to search. This can be set in solrconfig.xml, so that no additional query parameter are necessary. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#qf_.28Query_Fields.29

Answer (score 1):

Try change your `combinedSearch` type to `text` and then regenerate the index.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I approached it. Instead of using * alias, I defined which fields to copy to my combined field. I also sat multiValued to false on my normal fields (title and description). Instead of defining my fields as string, I used "text_general" - both for my normal fields and my combined field.

Furthermore I set "stored=false" on my combined field, as I don't need to return the value, as it is only used for searching - in my case at least.

```
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

<field name="combinedSearch" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="title" dest="combinedSearch"/>
<copyField source="description" dest="combinedSearch"/>

<uniqueKey>title</uniqueKey> 
<defaultSearchField>combinedSearch</defaultSearchField>
```

Comment: There is no need to set title and description as text_general since the copy happens before the analysis. Setting just the field combinedSearch to text_general is fine.